# How can I force my jenkinsfile parallel steps to use different agents?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile. It has parallel stages. Those stages need to run on agents with a label `pool_of_builder_nodes`.

The problem is, it always runs both run on the SAME agent with different executors! (technically both apply to the label). Short of explicitly picking agents by name, how can I force it to use different agents for parallel stages?

The thing I'm doing doesn't work well with multiple instances on the same host (but the agents CAN do other things at the same time, so I don't necessarily want to restrict them to a single executor).

```
pipeline {
    agent none // each stage has its own agent defined

    stages {
        stage('Parallel steps') {
            parallel {
                stage('Build Release') {
                    agent { 
                        label 'pool_of_builder_nodes'
                    }
                    steps {
                        // do the thing!
                    }
                }
                stage('Build Debug') {
                    agent { 
                        label 'pool_of_builder_nodes'
                    }
                    steps {
                        // also do the thing!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of top-level `agent none` and stage-level agents with identical  labels?

Comment: If I define the agent at the pipeline level, it runs the entire pipeline on a single agent's workspace (so, two processes are trying to pull from the same scm into the same directory at the same time). If I define them at the stage level, they at least use different workspaces (even if they frequently run on the same agent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find to do this was sub-optimal, but worked.

1. Re-factor each Stage into its own independent job. Have each stage invoke that job with the [build](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) step.
2. Install the [Throttle Concurrent Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) plugin.
3. Configure each job to use the same 'Throttle Category' and then set "Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node" to 1.

The end result is that each stage is actually an independent job, and the plugin won't let more than one instance run on the same node.